# Is there any symbol for "not relevant"?

Tags: notation

Just to represent to someone else that reads some expression, is there any nice symbol way to say something like this

$d/dx$[1]*($\sin^2x+2x^5-4x+\cos^4x$)

with a rapresentation for the reader like this

= $d/dx$[1]*($\sin^2x+2x^5-4x+\cos^4x$)

= $d/dx$[1]*(something not relevant)

My idea was this, but I don't know if it's the right notation

= $d/dx$[1]*($...$)

Thanks!

Comment: "$(\ldots)$" ought to be easily understandable by a human reader -- and human readers are all you need to care about, because robots don't _need_ to have pointed out that this subexpression is irrelevant for the next step.

Comment: I know of no precise notation for "not relevant", but in practice it is quite common to see things like $f(x) = x^2 + (\text{higher order terms})$ (which, in this particular case, has a nice notation, $O(x^3)$), $+ \text{(lower order terms)}$, $+(\text{similar terms with $b$ in place of $a$})$, etc., depending on the context of the problem. What might qualify as irrelevant depends on what you're trying to do, of course!

Comment: Keep in mind that the point of good notation is to be clear and efficient (notwithstanding that these two goals frequently conflict).  If people have to scratch their heads trying to figure out what you are thinking of, that's bad notation.

Comment: You can also just use a function symbol like $R(x)$, and explain afterwards that $R(x)$ is some irrelevant term.

Comment: How about $\frac{d}{dx} 1 \cdot \left( \text{whatever lol} \right)$?

Comment: @William spoken language specific, not so universal

Comment: I know. I was joking. The point is, if your message gets understood by people then you can use whatever symbols (no pun intended) you want. However if you want to stick to something a little standard then what Trebor said. But even so, one could ask what is R(x)? Where is it defined, does it take complex values? and so on...

Comment: What does $d/dx$[1]* mean?

Comment: When you write formulas, don't write for example `$\sin^2x$+$2x^5$-4x+$\cos^4x$`, going in and out of mathematics mode. Just write `$\sin^2x+2x^5-4x+\cos^4x$`. It's the correct way, and also easier to type.